"Double subscript" under a summation
I am trying to write out the equation for inclusion-exclusion for sets, however i have no clue how i can type out the second summation. An image of what i am trying to type is attached.
I am struggling with the second summation, where
$I{\subseteq}{1,...,n}$
is written below the capital sigma, but below that is
$|I|=k$


amsmath \substack

Welcome. // LaTeX is powerful/complex, and often there are several routes to obtain a result, some good routes, some bad. So please make it a habit, to post only code which will compile after we copied it. If it does, you kill many birds with one stone, like: showed your attempt, gave all relevant information (preamble),  perhaps created a more focused excerpt, allow the seasoned users to spot your probelm at a glance, obtaining more focuse/useful answers, etc. Thank you
